# Showing that $\int_0^a f(x)dx=2\int_0^{a/2} f(x)dx$, when $f(a-x) = f(x)$

Tags: integration

I'm still a noob regarding integration, and I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

> Show that $$\int_0^a f(x)dx=2\int_0^{a/2} f(x)dx$$ when $f(a-x) = f(x)$.

Comment: Split the original integral into $\int_0^{a/2}f(x)dx+\int_{a/2}^af(x)dx$

Comment: Split the original integral as kingW3 said and then use the substitution $u=a-x$

Comment: Do what Popular Power said in the second integral of kingW3.

Comment: Apply the strategy described by user35508 to employ the substitution defined by Popular Power in the splitting suggested by kingW3. Then rearrange the result to solve for $\int_0^a f(x)dx$.

Comment: @halrankard2 Great, You continued the pattern of conversation well. I am sure the OP can solve this now.

Comment: @user35508 Yes I was getting caught up in memories of the old "cumulative" folk songs like  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rattlin%27_Bog

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_0^a f(x)~dx=\int_0^{a/2} f(x)~dx~+~\int^a_{a/2} f(x)~dx=I_1~+~I_2$$
Let $~t=a-x\implies x=a-t~,$ so $~dx=-dt~.$
When $~x\to a/2~,~~t\to a/2~$ and 
When $~x\to a~,~~t\to 0~.$
Now $$I_2=\int^a_{a/2} f(x)~dx=-\int^0_{a/2} f(a-t)~dt~=\int_0^{a/2} f(a-t)~dt~=~\int_0^{a/2} f(a-x)~dx$$
Therefore,
$$I=\int_0^{a/2} f(x)~dx~+~\int_0^{a/2} f(a-x)~dx=2\int_0^{a/2} f(x)dx~,$$ if $~f(a-x) = f(x)~.$