# Tips on how to start calculating a definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

i would appreciate if you could help me with this problem.
I don't want the answer only how should i proceed with solving an integral like this
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x \sin^{2018}(x)}{\cos^{2018}(x)+\sin^{2018}(x)}dx$$
I am completely overwhelmed on how to proceed with this and i am stuck. so i would appreciate some tips to start.

after reading the tips i have done this
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{(\pi-x) \sin^{2018}(\pi-x)}{\cos^{2018}(\pi-x)+\sin^{2018}(\pi-x)}dx$$

after that i distributed it
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\pi\sin^{2018}(\pi-x)-x\sin^{2018}(\pi-x)}{\cos^{2018}(\pi-x)+\sin^{2018}(\pi-x)}=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\pi\sin^{2018}(x)}{\cos^{2018}(x)+\sin^{2018}(x)}-I$$
But after that i'm lost again, i know i should be look for a way to make some terms cancel but that's as far as i got

**please don't give me the direct solution, i would like to solve it by myself**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't gone through the details, but I would first try to enforce $u=\pi -x$ and see where that leads me.

Comment: I would start with $u=\frac{\pi}{2}-x.$ One of obtained integrals is zero (odd function), the function in the second integral can be transformed in a rational function, ... but I am not sure if it helps.

Comment: I found it is almost $\frac{\pi ^2}{4}$

Comment: Where does this integral come from?

Comment: I have edited my answer. I hope you can do it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\,\mathrm dx$$

---

**Edit:** Since you are still stuck after performing the above step, you get $$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{(\pi-x) \sin^{2018}(x)}{\cos^{2018}(x)+\sin^{2018}(x)}\, \,\mathrm dx$$
and add this to $I$ to get $$2I=\pi \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{ \sin^{2018}(x)}{\cos^{2018}(x)+\sin^{2018}(x)}\,\mathrm dx $$

If you are still stuck, use the property

> $\displaystyle \int_0^{2a}f(x)\,\mathrm dx=2\int_0^a f(x)\,\mathrm dx$, when $f(2a-x)=f(x)$. If you are unaware of this property, you may see it's proof in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849924/showing-that-int-0a-fxdx-2-int-0a-2-fxdx-when-fa-x-fx?noredirect=1) answer.

I hope, now you can take it from here.

Comment: Can you please show how do you get the exact value of $I$? I just managed to get that it is almost $\pi^2/4$. Almost...

Comment: @Raffaele: It is exactly equal to $\pi^2/4$.  Use the property in the spoiler and change the limit from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and  you would get simply $\displaystyle 2I=\pi \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \,\mathrm dx$

Comment: @Raffaele: If you say, I will write it in the solution as well.

Comment: No, thank you. I got it. $2018$ or $0$ is the same

Comment: I hope it's not too late but i noticed that after doing the substitution of $\pi-x$ wouldn't $\sin(\pi-x)=\cos(x)$, how did you get the $I=(\pi-x) \sin(x)$ part?

Comment: @Ramirogenta: Well, you need to check it out again. $\sin(\pi -x)=\sin(x)\ne \cos(x)$.

Comment: and @Ramirogenta I didn't substitute for $\pi-x$, rather I used the property $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\,\mathrm dx$, which is although the same thing as substituting for $\pi-x$, but I felt to tell you that the two operations are different which yield the same result.